# API Authentication/Authorization Granularity Best Practices

Tags: rest, authentication, http, oauth-2.0

I am building a REST API. I am planning to secure it using `auth0` and I am entertaining different options reagarding how external clients will access it. One of the ideas I had, was to provide 3 different types of endpoints:

1. **Secure**: This type requires role-based access control (RBAC) and once a client is authenticated all actions are available
2. **Insecure**: This type has no form of authentication/authorization. Anyone can access the API remotely. No credentials//tokens are required.
3. **Partial secure**: I was imagining this API as a partially authenticated API. It would reside behind an attribute-based access control (ABAC) which would be defined from the HTTP requests themselves. e.g. if the POST body contains `channel=secure-request` we need to properly authorize the user that is making it.

And then comes the afterthought: Aren't options 1 and 3 in principle the same? Can they not be consolidated? If there's no role-based authentication and I only use attribute-based authorization can I not achieve the same result?

I think the answer is yes if the outcome of the authentication is to gauge access to a resource i.e. a specific API endpoint. I cannot find any reason why someone would use RBAC to allow access to an API only to revoke this access by afterward checking the attributes of the request (ABAC) and realizing that the resource cannot be accessed from that user.

Am I right? Are there any best practices one should follow when aiming for this "granular" authentication/authorization of an API?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, partially secure API seems to suggest API functions that contain sensitive and nonsensitive content alike. So, your API serves secretive and public content. That would mean that something like the following pseudo-code would be executed:

```
display(public content)
if (secure) then
    display(secure content)
end if
```

As we can see, partially secure API in principle differs from secure API in sensibly responding to requests with useful data, whose degree and depth depends on the security of the request.

Now, one may argue that a partially secure API can be viewed as a combination of secure and insecure APIs, but that's only true in principle, but not in practice.

In practice, the separation of partially secure API into secure and insecure parts (or the other way around) probably requires some refactoring and it is up to the decision-makers to decide whether it makes sense to have partially secure APIs.